# List from dynamic Class does not generate Key

Tags: list, class, c#-4.0, dynamic

I try to generate a `List<>` from a dynamic Class, with help of one person here I came a little further however not what I need

I need this: imgur.com/OIiYQ0f

I have this: imgur.com/9shrhu6

Whatever I try I cant seems to get the right output, also do not understand the difference what I have and what should have (the key with the name), would be awesome if somebody could kill this problem and explain what is the difference
My code:

```
foreach (DataRow r in _data.Rows)
{
DynamicClass dynamicClass = new DynamicClass();

foreach (String Property in Properties)
{
    dynamicClass.Property[Property.ToString()] = _data.Rows[i][Property].ToString(); 
}
    DynamicClassList.Add(dynamicClass);
}

[DebuggerTypeProxy(typeof(DynamicClassProxy))]
public class DynamicClass
{
    // property is a class that will create dynamic properties at runtime
    private DynamicProperty _property = new DynamicProperty();

    public DynamicProperty Property
    {
        get { return _property; }
        set { _property = value; }
    }

    [DebuggerDisplay("{value}", Name = "{key,nq}")]
    private class KeyValuePair
    {
        private object key;
        private object value;

        public KeyValuePair(KeyValuePair<string, object> kvp)
        {
            this.value = kvp.Value;
            this.key = kvp.Key;
        }
    }

    private class DynamicClassProxy
    {
        private DynamicClass _dynamicClass;
        public DynamicClassProxy(DynamicClass dynamicClass)
        {
            _dynamicClass = dynamicClass;
        }

        [DebuggerBrowsable(DebuggerBrowsableState.RootHidden)]
        public KeyValuePair[] Keys
        {
            get
            {
                return _dynamicClass.Property.properties.Select(x => new KeyValuePair(x)).ToArray();
            }
        }
    }

    public class DynamicProperty
    {
        //Make it so no one can create these objects.
        internal DynamicProperty() { }

        // a Dictionary that hold all the dynamic property values
        internal Dictionary<string, object> properties = new Dictionary<string, object>();

        // the property call to get any dynamic property in our Dictionary, or "" if none found.
        public object this[string name]
        {
            get
            {
                if (properties.ContainsKey(name))
                {
                    return properties[name];
                }
                return "";
            }
            set
            {
                properties[name] = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Your need and have images are the same...?

Comment: I am pretty sure they where not...., anyway changed it

Comment: why don't you explain what you're trying to accomplish instead of asking to "fix my code make it look like this instead of that"

Comment: I dont ask this, however I cant get the Key value no matter how I try, if I run the static Class it works correct as you see in the image, just cant find the solution for this. The Key value I need for the client there I use it for a jQuery object, what I have now does not work and returns the objects but shown up as undefined. The Keys I use for selecting the right object and on [0] I cant build a reference on